# Doubt in proof of proposition 4.2.2 iii) in Meyn and Tweedie

Tags: markov-chains

Proposition 4.2.2 in Meyn and Tweedie's Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability, which can be found [here](http://probability.ca/MT/Chap4.pdf), reads as follows:

> If $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is $\varphi$-irreducible w.r.t a measure $\varphi$ over $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$, then there exists a probability measure $\psi$ over $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ s.t.:
>
> 1. $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is $\psi$-irreducible.
> 2. For any other measure $\varphi'$, the chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is $\varphi'$-irreducible iff $\psi \succ \varphi'$ .
> 3. If $\psi(A)=0$, then $\psi(\{y:L(y,A)>0\})=0$.
> 4. $\psi$ is equivalent to:
>    $$
>    \psi'(A):= \int_{\mathcal{X}} \varphi'(dy)K_{a \frac{1}{2}}(y,A)
>    $$
>    for any other irreducible measure $\varphi'$.

The proof of the third assertion reads:

> We have that:
> $$
> \int_{\mathcal{X}} \psi(dy)P^m(y,A)2^{-m}=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \varphi(dy)\sum_{n \geq 0} P^{m+n}(y,A)2^{-(n+m-1)} \leq \psi(A)
> $$
> from which $3)$ follows immediately.

I don't see how this inequality proves the assertion, i.e. how $\int_{\mathcal{X}} \psi(dy)P^m(y,A)2^{-m}=0$ implies that $\psi(\{y:L(y,A)>0\})=0$.

Here, $\psi$ is the measure given by:
$$
\psi(A)=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \varphi(dy)K_{a \frac{1}{2}}(y,A),
$$
$L(y,A)$ is the kernel given by:
$$
L(y,A)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_A<\infty \, | \, X_0=y),
$$
where $\tau_A=\min\{n \geq 1: X_n \in A\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but in case anyone has the same issue.

You're right that it's not enough that $\int_{\mathcal{X}} \psi(dy)P^m(y,A)2^{-m}=0$ for a fixed $m$. However, this implies by the monotone convergence theorem that $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} \psi(dy)\sum_{m\in \mathbb{N}}P^m(y,A)2^{-m}=0,$$
If an integral of a non-negative function with respect to $\psi$ equals zero, that function must equal zero $\psi$-almost everywhere (by the definition of the Lebesgue integral). Since $$L(y,A) > 0 \iff \exists ~ m : P^m(y,A)>0 \iff \sum_m P^m(y,A) 2^{-m} > 0,$$ we deduce the claim.